# Dominoes on chessboard

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry, tiling

A $2016\times 2016$ chessboard is tiled with $2 \times  1$ dominoes.

I can prove that there is a grid line that pass through at least $505$ dominoes.

But how to prove or disprove that there is a grid line that pass through at least $506$ dominoes?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is very clear. Why $505$ dominoes ? If you have a $2016\times 2016$ chessboard tiled with $2\times 1$ dominoes, then each line has $1008$ dominoes, unless I am wrong...

Comment: That is not true for all possible tiling

Answer (score 4):

:-) Each grid line intersects an even number of dominoes.

Comment: In case it's not clear, this observation together with the OP's proof for 505 dominoes gives the result for 506. I'd like to see how @Bless proved it for 505 and not 506 though, to me it seems a little odd. (Pun totally intended.)

Comment: @JoshChen In the chessboard are $2\cdot 2015$ grid lines. Aslo there are $2016^2/2$ interesections of dominoes with grid lines. So there is a grid line which intersects at least $2016^2/(4\cdot 2015)\simeq 504.25\dots$ dominoes.

Comment: Thank you. But why each grid line intersects an even number of dominoes?

Comment: @Bless Each grid line divides the chessboard into two parts. Each of these parts contains an even number (multiple of 2016) chesscells. So it contains some number of full dominoes and an *even* number of domino halves (which are cut by the grid line).

Comment: OK  I get it :).